# Parsing XML in SQL without a namespace

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

The code will be self explanatory to the right person for this, but any questions please shout...

Thanks,
Dave

```sql
DECLARE @XML XML

SET @XML = 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<updates>
  <versions>
<installer type="A" Xversion="101" iniSizeInBytes="22480" dataSizeInBytes="23396349" msiSizeInBytes="4732928" />
<installer type="B" Yversion="201" iniSizeInBytes="22480" dataSizeInBytes="116687353" msiSizeInBytes="5807616" webconfigModifierSizeInBytes="11800" />
<installer type="A" Xversion="102" iniSizeInBytes="22480" dataSizeInBytes="23396349" msiSizeInBytes="4732928" />
<installer type="B" Yversion="202" iniSizeInBytes="22480" dataSizeInBytes="116687353" msiSizeInBytes="5807616" webconfigModifierSizeInBytes="11800" />
  </versions>
  <update setNumber="1" XVersion="101" YVersion="201">
    <detail Ref="1000">some detail info for 101 and 201</detail>
  </update>
  <update setNumber="2" XVersion="102" YVersion="202">
    <detail Ref="1001">some detail info for 102 and 202</detail>
  </update>
</updates>
'


SELECT
    r.value('@ref','NVARCHAR(250)') as 'Ref', --This is wrong, but you can probably see i'm wanting the value of Ref, eg 1000 for line 1, 1001 for line 2
    t.r.query('./detail').value('.','nvarchar(max)') as 'Detail'
FROM    @XML.nodes('/updates/update') AS t(r);
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: sql server, added tags sorry. Specifically has to work with 2008r2+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `detail` element in `value` method to get the value in `Ref` attribute

```sql
SELECT
      r.value('@Ref','NVARCHAR(250)') as 'Ref',  -- It should be @Ref instead of @ref
      r.query('.').value('.','nvarchar(max)') as 'Detail'
FROM    @XML.nodes('/updates/update/detail') AS t(r);
```

**Note :** `Elements` and `attributes` in xml is case sensitive you cannot use `@ref` in query when xml `attribute` is `Ref`

- **[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/WPMGP51404)**

Comment: Thanks! I had tried that with @ref and didn't think of case sensitivity!

Comment: One problem though, the [1] makes it only return the first detail line? You wouldn't have known from the bad example i gave, but there are multiple detail nodes in each update node

Comment: Brill thanks :) is it possible to also obtain setNumber="1" from the updates node?

Comment: Thanks, researching it looks like i need to be using cross apply some how, will have a play around and raise it up if i cant find it. Thanks for the help so far though, i can work with this =)

Comment: Sorted.... no cross apply needed.... r.value('(../@setNumber)[1]','NVARCHAR(250)') as 'setNumber'     thanks again!